# GKE "Enable auto-upgrade" setting cannot be toggled off

Tags: settings, google-kubernetes-engine, upgrade

I use GKE to host and manage a kubernetes cluster. GKE will update it's nodes automatically by default. Per this documentation the setting can be toggled on or off. (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades)

However, I am unable to disable this feature. The option is grayed out. Does anyone know why? I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation or answers online.

[Screenshot of option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7m1g.png)

Answer (score 5):

Surely as soon as I humble myself and publicly ask a question I find the answer on my own. :-)

First the Cluster "Release Channel" needs to be set to a specific version. Once this is set you will be able to change the behavior of the node pools.

Answer (score 1):

Previous speaker is right. Below the answer from google support service to my request:

Node-auto-upgrades are always enabled if your cluster is enrolled in a release channel. [You will find this information on this part of the document.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades#disable) You will need to set that configuration to a static channel before trying to disable the nodes auto-upgrades. You can find this configuration to be edited here in your cluster information panel.